# Azure AD OpenID-Connect code not working if requested url and redirect URL are not same

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

Azure AD OpenID-Connect code not working if requested URL and redirect URL are not same.
My plan is Site A => Request Azure AD Azure AD Authenticates and Redirect to => Site B
Site B => Give Access to Site A

Comment: Please add more details like error message seen, configuration details on the redirection etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the web address when you are logged in , Paste it in note pad and check redirect url in the authentication request with the url in azure ad portal.

During authentication , the whole process is controlled by OpenID Connect middleware , after user validate credential in Azure's login page ,Azure Ad will redirect user back to your application's redirect url which is set in OIDC's configuration

Please check this doc on
[Redirect URI (reply URL) restrictions - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url)

> 1. Redirect URIs must begin with  https scheme.
> 2. Redirect URIs are case-sensitive and must match the case of the URL path of your running application. For example, if your application
>    includes as part of its path .../abc/response-oidc, do not specify
>    .../ABC/response-oidc in the redirect URI. The HTTPS scheme (https://)
>    is supported for all HTTP-based redirect URIs. The HTTP scheme
>    (http://) is supported only for localhost URIs.
> 3. The redirect url you set(in AuthenticationProperties) is to control which page/action should be redirect after authentication .